# Laravel I need to select Id where supplier name are similar

Tags: laravel

here is the code

```
$supplier_id=Supplier::where('supplier', $itest_supplier)->get('supplier_id');
```

I'm trying to get the id where supplier from the model = to the supplier in $itest_supplier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a single Supplier:

```php
$supplier_id = Supplier::where('supplier', $itest_supplier)->value('supplier_id');
```

If you are looking for multiple Suppliers:

```php
$supplier_ids = Supplier::where('supplier', $itest_supplier)->pluck('supplier_id');
```

Comment: No need; I can edit things directly, but I always give the author a chance to do the edit themselves 

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the id of suppliers that match your $itest_supplier

then

```
$supplier_id=Supplier::where('supplier', $itest_supplier)
->select('id')
->get();
```

but if you want to get  suppliers with simliar name you could use like

```
$supplier_id=Supplier::where('supplier','like','%'. $itest_supplier .'%')
->get();
```